# Localization file in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: localization, translation, game-development, unreal-engine4

I wanted to try to make a fan translation, and I searched for the localization file through umodel, I managed to find it, but the program does not see that there is something in the folder

[umodel_problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fCfB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you've figured out the answer to your question by this time, but seeing how there are no answers so far and just in case you still haven't found a solution, try using Fmodel to extract the locres file in the localization folder, or you can always unpack the whole pak file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).